# RawQuery data cursor showing empty field

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I try to pull data from database by using RawQuery method, but it seems I get empty rows. Actually data is present in the database which I am try to pull. Can anyone find my mistake?

```
db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

String selectSQL = "Select * from " + Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME
                + " where " + Wish_list_Table.COL_CATEGORY + " = ?";

String[] add = { " HOME" };

TextView textView = getGenericView();
Cursor selectdata = db.rawQuery(selectSQL, add);
Log.i("select", "" + selectdata.getCount());
```

This class for database table property......

```
public static abstract class Wish_list_Table implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "WISH_LIST1";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_TIME = "TIME";

    public static final String COL_DATE = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_CATEGORY = "CATEGORY";

    public static final String COL_DESC = "DESC";

}
```

this is DATABASE IMAGE...

[image]

Comment: could you please show a part of your database where the category Home is present ? and are you sure HOME is capitalized and note Home or home ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
String[] add = { " HOME" };
```

Don't you see there's a **SPACE** before "HOME"?
It will never match the values in the db!

So you'll always get an empty Cursor.
Replace that statement with this:

```
String[] add = { "HOME" };
```

And you'll get all the records where CATEGORY equals 'HOME'

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like the following :

```
   String[] add = { "HOME" };

        String [] columns = {"NAME" , "CATEGORY"};


        Cursor cursor = db.query(Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME, columns,  Wish_list_Table.COL_CATEGORY + " = ?", add, null, null, null)

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ArrayList_table.COL_NAME));
                textView.setText(name);
            }
            cursor.close();
```

but make sure the data in the database is present .